# TCP/IP connection with local router

Tags: tcpclient, tcp

My PC is connected to wireless router.

I checked my router's ip using this site http://www.myipaddress.com/, and typing "ipconfig" in command get a local ip which is different from the router's ip.

What I want to do is making a tcp/ip server using my PC and connecting to my PC with smartphone.

In this situation, While running server program in my PC, what I have done in my smartphone are

1. To set server's ip with router's ip
2. To set server's ip with local pc ip(of course, it should not work)

Both of them does not work. How to connect the smartphone to my PC by tcp/ip connection?

Comment: Configure port forwarding on your router.

Comment: Thanks @melpomene. This is what I looking for

Answer (score 0):

To connect smartphone to you PC you need some public IP address/TCP port that are mapped to your PC's IP address/Port.

Public IP address could be assigned to either:

- Your PC
- Router

In first case you do not need anything special - just connect your smartphone to PC by public IP address.

In second case you need to configure router to pass traffic to your PC. Usually this feature called "Port forwarding" or "Virtual Servers".

Another and the best solution is to deploy you server on some internet hosting site with public IP address.

Comment: How to know my public IP of my PC? When I type "ipconfig" in cmd, I got local ip of the router. Also, using the web I commented above I just got router's public IP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the solution with port forwarding which is commented above.

Comment: Right, I've just added some explanation to somebody who may have the same question.

Comment: About ipconfig - your PC either has or not has public IP address. If it has it is returned by ipconfig. Router also can have or not have public IP. And to it is important for router to have it if you use port forwarding and access to you PC from outside via this router.